# Model diagnostic plots for anova test

Tags: statistical-significance, diagnostic

Could you please help me in interpreting the model diagnostic plots? I feel there is a problem with the scale-location plot?
[image]

Comment: There is a conspicuous kink in the red line. So, that should be a red flag.

Comment: @User1865345 Thank you very much for your reply. What does that mean how should I check this?

Comment: Please refer ISLR (https://www.statlearning.com/) book to understand the model diagnostic plots. In-depth discussion of model assumptions and why those are important etc can be found in econometrics books (by Greene or by Damodar Gujrati)

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi to check the homoscedasticity assumption more formally, resort to Breusch-Pagan test.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. I don't usually test things like homoscedasticity, because it isn't reasonable to imagine that it exists for real situations. Thus, you know the null hypothesis is false in advance. What matters is the magnitude & nature of the deviation from perfectly constant variance. That's why you look at plots (as you're doing). In general a rule of thumb is that ANOVA (or other linear model) is robust to deviations when the SDs differ by <2 times. That seems to be the case here. If you want to use a robust SE for testing, that's fine, but this doesn't look like a big deal.

Comment: @gung - Reinstate Monica , Thank you very much for your reply I really appreciate it.